# Debian preseed.cfg partman specify_usage for news

Tags: debian, preseed

I am trying to utilize partman as part of a packer built base image.  We need to declare the root system as a 'news' usage to increase the number of inodes.  I cannot enable usage flags for the partman if I declare the partition either in expert_recipe or partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic.

```
# Partitioning
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-auto/disk   string /dev/sda
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
# Does not work, ie news usage
#d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
#highinode_disk :: \
#  29000 10 -1 ext4 \
#    $primary{ } \
#   $bootable{ } \
#   method{ format } \
#   format{ } \
#   use_filesystem{ news } \
#   filesystem{ ext4 } \
#    specify_usage{ news } \
#   mountpoint{ / } .
#d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe highinode_disk
d-i partman/default_filesystem string ext4
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/specify_usage select news
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/text/specify_mountpoint /
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
```

How do I trigger news typical usage on the main partition using preseed.cfg?

Thanks!

Comment: have you considered using XFS or btrfs instead of ext4?

Comment: Thanks but, I would rather work around the issue with hand scripted later partition creation than consider more exotic filesystems.  There should be a proper way to do this with partman.

In my experience, I would never put XFS in a production environment as its journaling is not safe and the tools are weak.

Answer (score -1):

specify_usage not work for ubuntu, i use next workaround for this issue

```
d-i partman/early_command string \ 
  sed -i 's/inode_ratio = 16384/inode_ratio = 4096/g' /etc/mke2fs.conf
```

Comment: You might want to expand this answer a bit, it's a little hard to follow and borders on being a comment, IMO.